# How do you create a transparent window using dispmanx on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sdl, pygame, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on a slideshow app and using SDL 1.2 using a custom dispmanx backend (https://github.com/vanfanel/SDL12-kms-dispmanx) with Pygame to create overlays on top of omxplayer.

It all works well and layers correctly, but I can't seem to make a transparent canvas in dispmanx without making my objects transparent as well. My understanding is Pygame itself cannot handle this and it is up to SDL to handle transparency between dispmanx layers.

My goal is a hardware accelerated transparent canvas the size of my screen above omxplayer that I can draw on.

I suspect there must be a method other than using the alpha settings in vc_dispmanx_element_add to do this? XBMC uses dispmanx and can do opaque overlays above omxplayer, so this must be possible. I've also looked at vc_dispmanx_display_set_background, but this seems to only take RGB and not an alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a transparent window u could take a screenshot of the window and use it as a background. To do this i used pyscreenshot to take the image (though there are other options) and

```
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS']="0,0"
```

to make sure the window is in the right spot every time, the only weakness to this is that the window is no longer transparent if something changes behind it

Comment: The omxplayer layer underneath will be playing video, so unfortunately I don't think this will work.

Comment: sorry about that, i had a similar problem and that was my solution, but i dont know much about omxplayer so i cant help much more

Answer (score 0):

Check out my library built for exactly this use case: https://github.com/dtcooper/python-dispmanx

You can use pygame as follows,

```py
from random import randint
import pygame
from dispmanx import DispmanX

# Generate a random color with alpha compontent
def random_color_with_alpha():
    return tuple(randint(0, 0xFF) for _ in range(3)) + (randint(0x44, 0xFF),)

display = DispmanX(pixel_format="RGBA")
surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(
    display.buffer, display.size, display.pixel_format
)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

for _ in range(20):
    surface.fill(random_color_with_alpha())
    display.update()
    clock.tick(2)
```

Alternately, there's an another C Python extension that I didn't write that also functions the same way: https://github.com/eclispe/pyDispmanx

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.